# Post data from an HTML web form to a SharePoint 2007 list

Tags: 2007, list-form

I am trying to collect data from my user on an HTML web page in a form.
Then I need for that data to post to the SharePoint list once the submit button is selected.
The webpage is on the same SharePoint site.
I would also like the ability for them to add an attachment if possible.

Comment: Can you use infopath 2007 for the form? is it MOSS 2007 or WSS?

Comment: I can use infopath 2007. But I do not know it well but i am open to option. the SP is 2007 that is all i know.

Answer (score 1):

In MOSS you can customize a list form in InfoPath 2007.. Or create an InfoPath form to submit data to custom list, you can [follow this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc162745%28v=office.12%29.aspx#ip2007SubmitDataSPList_OverviewofSubmittingDatafromInfoPathForms) to get complete knowledge on how you can post data to MOSS List using InfoPath form!

Why I recommend InfoPath form because there you have an attachment control as well and you can bind that control to list item attachments, and [here is the usage of Attachment Control](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/insert-a-file-attachment-control-HP010080908.aspx)